# I can't install tux-paint , tux-math , tux-typing ,k geography. please tall me how to install this app in ubuntu software?

Tags: software-installation

I can't install tux-paint , tux-math , tux-typing ,k geography.
please tall me how to install this app in ubuntu software?

Answer (score 1):

You can install them by running these commands from the Terminal:

```
sudo apt install tuxpaint tuxmath tuxtype kgeography
```